# Netbeans C++ error: 193

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, mingw

I wrote this simple program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "hello" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and I get the following error:

Cannot run program "C:\MinGW\bin\automake-1.10" (in directory "C:\Users\palmovitsch\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CppApplication_1"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 ist keine zul�ssige Win32-Anwendung

BUILD FAILED (exit value -2, total time: 62ms)

I tried to reinstall MinGW, MSYS and msysDTK
I have added all to the path environment variable
;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

Comment: Modify your settings for C++ projects inside Netbeans and use the `make.exe` tool from msys instead of automake from mingw. For my system the path is `C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that Netbeans does not work on my machine for C/C++ code as well (did not use it for C development in a while). Now it works again with the following workaround:

Change the setting `Make Command` in `Tools->Options` under the tab `C/C++` to plain `make.exe` instead of the whole path to `make.exe`.

This asssumes that the bin folder that contains make.exe is correctly set in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Run Netbeans as Administrator.

If problem continues then you may not have installed plugin for c/c++ in Netbeans. Go to https://netbeans.org/community/releases/60/cpp-setup-instructions.html

Check if you installed plugin or not.